# Downloading PDF from app is not working on Android 11

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-file

I want to download PDF in my app and show it in PDF viewer. I'm not using temp file, because I don't want to have randomized file name (on some devices it caused "file name too long" error). It is working perfectly on all devices except Android 11. (I dont even need to have storage permission turned on in app settings in order to download that PDF). But just in case I have <`uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` in my manifest.

It is causing this error:

```
open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) Can't open file
```

Here is code used for downloading and parsing data to my PDF:

```
val dlg = Dialog(a).apply {
            setMessage(R.string.downloading)
            setNegativeButton {
                downloadTask?.cancel()
            }
            show()
        }
        downloadTask = asyncTask({
            try {
                val dir = app.externalCacheDir!!
                dir.mkdirs()
                File(dir, "client-invoice.pdf").also { f ->
                    f.deleteOnExit()
                    URL(receiptUrl).openStream().use { s ->
                        FileOutputStream(f).use { d ->
                            s.copyTo(d)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e
            }
        }, onDone = {
            downloadTask = null
            dlg.dismiss()
        }){ r->
            try {
                if (r is Exception) {
                    throw r
                } else if (r is File) {
                    tempFile = r
                    val int = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
                        setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + r.absolutePath), "application/pdf")
                    }
                    startActivityForResult(int, 1)
                }
            } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                tempFile?.delete()
                a.openPlayStoreLinkWithDialog("com.google.android.apps.pdfviewer", "PDF")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                app.showToast(e.message?:"")
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried using `android:preserveLegacyExternalStorage="true"` tag in manifest file?

Comment: Yes, but its not working either.

Comment: For downloading you only need internet permission. Storage permissions are needed for creating files or folders. It looks as you have a problem creating a file.

Comment: Only call mkdirs if the directory does not exist yet. And if you call it then check return value. And if false then stop as it makes no sense trying to create a file in a directory that does not exist.

Comment: Tell full path of directory please. `Can't open file` So which file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file` as a `Uri` scheme effectively has been banned since Android 7.0. You should be crashing with a `FileUriExposedException`. Use `FileProvider` and `getUriForFile()` to make your content available to other apps, as they cannot access files in your app's app-specific locations on external storage.

Then, you can get rid of whatever hack you applied to get past the `FileUriExposedException`.